# Передача объекта по указателю в функцию, а потом изменение самого указателя

Tags: указатели, c++

Дело вот в чем. Имеется функция

```
void F(T *a){
  delete a;
  a = NULL;
}
```

Она вызывается так

```
int main(){
cOBJECT *head; // Создается указатель на экземпляр класса, или объект структурного типа
  .........
  F(head); // Передаем указатель на объект
  return 0;
}
```

Проблема вот в чем. В функции F я удаляю объект. Но не происходит изменения значения указателя. Кто знает, в чем проблема?

Comment: Поскольку речь идет об объектах и классах, метку "с" убрал

Comment: Я просто забыл дописать ... Исправлю щас на структуру

Comment: В C (и в C++ -- ссылки не трогаем) параметры передаются по значению. Т.е. значение параметра в функции вы можете менять как угодно, в вызывающей функции он не изменится

Comment: Вот в каком случай она у меня выходит. del(&(serch(head)));
функция seach(head) возвращает указатель на объект. А функция del реализовано так del(coBJECT **a);

Answer (score 4):

- Где у вас вызов `new` для объекта?
- Указатель в функцию `F` передается по значению, то есть по сути ваш код имеет примерно следующий смысл:

  ```
  void F(int a) {
      // ...
      a = 0;
  }
  ```
- Естественно, что в таком случае с `head` в функции `main` ничего не произойдет.
- Для того, чтобы *можно было изменить* `head` в функции `F(...)`, его нужно передавать по ссылке (`&`) или как указатель на указатель (`T**`)

Comment: new я опустил .. просто так.
А как тогда сделать доступ к полям по указателю
до этого делал, так
a->count = max;
А теперь как вы говорите, надо так что ли.
**a->count = max;

Comment: @Ruzel

- `(*a)->count = max`

- Подумайте, действительно ли вам нужно менять значение указателя, передавая его в функцию. Обычно можно изменить логику приложения, чтобы этого делать не пришлось.

Comment: У меня времени нету.. придумывать новую логику. Заказчик мало времени дал. Ща попробую так.

Comment: Соболезную заказчику.

Comment: А в main в функцию F как должно передаваться этот указатель..
F(&head) или F(*head)

Comment: @Ruzel `F(&head)`

Comment: Что означает эта ошибка (lvalue required as unary '&' operand)

Comment: Так что написано, то и означает. В качестве параметра может использоваться только то, что может стоять в левой части операции присваивания, т.е. то, чему можно присвоить значение

Answer (score 1):

Это не проблема, а типичное поведение. Хорошим стилем будет присвоить этому указателю заведомо неверное значение самостоятельно, например, NULL.

Comment: Пробовал после delete присвоить NULL. Никакой

Comment: Исходному указателю в main и присвойте. Почему не меняется 
"head", если вы поменяете "a", вам написал @Котик\_хочет\_кушать.

Но даже если вы вызовете delete в main, head тоже не изменится - сам по себе delete просто возвращает память, выделенную оператором new, обратно в кучу, указатель продолжает хранить тот же адрес.

Comment: Не вы не так поняли.. жизнь этого указателя зависит в функции F. А в main я просто создаю и ни че больше.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы можно было изменить значения указателя, достаточно изменить сигнатуру функции F следующим образом:

```
void F(T &* a)
{
  // do something..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Иногда проще результат передавать в качестве возвращаемого значения, чем извращаться с двойными указателями:

```
T * F(T * a) {
  delete a;
  a = NULL;
  return a;
}

...
head = F(head);
...
```

Comment: Суть теперь в том что я могу удалить... но не могу изменить адрес указателя.. Все пробовал все равно!

Comment: Какой еще адрес указателя?

Comment: Как я понял `T * a`. И это правильно. Язык такой. Надо этот указатель менять -- пусть передаёт указатель на него `T **a`

Comment: Ну так я предлагаю чтобы функция возвращала измененный указатель.